# NMSSH error on build

Tags: ios

I am trying to use NMSSH to send ssh commande on my Raspberry Pi from an Ios applications but when I run it, I get the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NMSFTP", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in NMSSHSession.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I ever had a similar problem resolved by adding libz.dylib library to my project, maybe I just have to do somethimg similar but i don't know what.

someone know how to solve it ?
thanks

Comment: up please, nobody can help ??

Comment: sorry to up again but I'm really confuse .(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it by myself, I just missed to add a library to  my project.